# Fancybox on Google Map markers is not working properly on tablet

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is the **situation**:

I am building an app that interacts with the markers of a Google Map, in order to display single images, slideshow or youtube videos.

On a desktop view is working fine, but on the tablet is not working properly.

The main issue is that the content of the markers is not show after touching the marker, but it needs at least a double click (while i need that they respond with a single click)
and sometimes i need to make 2/3 attempts before the content is displayed.

This is the **example**:

http://jsbin.com/ANuyojoW/26/edit

http://jsbin.com/ANuyojoW/26

This is the **question**:

***How can i make the markers respond instantly with a single touch?***

I have tried two days trying to figure out the issue, but unfortunately did not find any solutions.

Hope somebody knows the answer!

Thank you very much!

p.s. i am testing with a Samsung galaxy tab 3 with Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using some other event? Maybe `mousedown` would be a solution.
[Full list of events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events):

1. 'click'
2. 'dblclick'
3. 'mouseup'
4. 'mousedown'
5. 'mouseover'
6. 'mouseout'

I cannot test this since I don't own a tablet, but I believe that's the problem.

Comment: I thought it could be something like that. Have already tried to use the event 'tap', but with the same result: fancybox load for a second and then disappear. But with a double touch then it opens the video.

Comment: Have tried. Is a bit better than click. But is not reliable yet. Sometimes work only after two preliminary touch. Sometimes works one time and no more. Is better since when it works, it works with just one touch and no with double, but unfortunately is not reliable. 
Have tested both on my app and in the jsbin demo and there is the same behavior.

Comment: Hmmm. Well all the available events are the above. You should check them all and see if there is something that does the job. Maybe mouseout is better. Just experiment with all of these.

Comment: Did you find the answer to your problem? If it was something from my answer please check it, if not, please provide an answer of your own and check that one.